# CXF jax-rs exception mapper selection order

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

There's a possibility to change the exception mapper selection order - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6568 (make default exception mapper least specific in order to use custom one's).
What's the correct way to set this property for every call to the specific jaxrs:server?
I've tried to add a section:

```
<jaxrs:properties>
      <entry key="default.wae.mapper.least.specific" value="true"/>
 </jaxrs:properties>
```

to the jaxrs:server configuration, but that didn't make a trick.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Current solution - ugly one. 
Message.put("default.wae.mapper.least.specific", true) in a new class extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor. The bean of this new class is the first in the jaxrs:interceptors list

Comment: Adding the property as you described works for me (using CXF 3.1.11)

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for exact configuration, here is what works for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:properties>
            <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6568 -->
            <entry key="default.wae.mapper.least.specific" value="true" />
        </cxf:properties>
    </cxf:bus>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with Java Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
public JAXRSServerFactoryBean cxfServer(final Bus cxfBus) {
  final JAXRSServerFactoryBean serverFactory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
  serverFactory.setBus(cxfBus);
  serverFactory.getBus().setProperty("default.wae.mapper.least.specific", true);

  ...

  serverFactory.setAddress("/");
  serverFactory.create();
  return serverFactory;
}
```